# You have an error in your SQL syntax; - and Undefined Variable error - possibly connected

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, syntax

I'm pretty new to coding with php and SQL, so I'm probably going to have a lot of questions.  But as the title states, I'm getting this error...

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

I'm not sure what this is referring to.  I've gone over the code as much as I can, but I can't find a syntax error.  Maybe it's something I just don't know yet.

```
<?php 
// including the database connection file
include_once("config.php");

if(isset($_POST['update']) && isset($_GET['site']))
{    
$sitenumber = $_POST['sitenumber'];
$videolink = $_POST['videolink'];
$daynight = $_POST['daynight'];
$maxtents = $_POST['maxtents'];
$maxpersons = $_POST['maxpersons'];
$geography = $_POST['geography'];
$view = $_POST['view'];
$forestcover = $_POST['forestcover'];
$waterfront = $_POST['waterfront'];
$firepit = $_POST['firepit'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$reslink = $_POST['reslink'];   

// checking empty fields
if(empty($sitenumber) || empty($videolink) || empty($daynight) || 
empty($maxtents) || empty($maxpersons) || empty($geography) || 
    empty($view) || empty($forestcover) || empty($waterfront) || 
empty($firepit) || empty($description) || empty($reslink)) {                
    if(empty($sitenumber)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>Site Number field is empty.</font><br/>";
    }

    if(empty($videolink)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>YouTube Link field is empty.</font><br/>";
    }

    if(empty($daynight)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>Day or overnight field is empty.</font> 
<br/>";
    }        

    if(empty($maxtents)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>Maximum Tents field is empty.</font><br/>";
    }

    if(empty($maxpersons)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>Maximum Persons field is empty.</font> 
 <br/>";
    }        

    if(empty($geography)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>Geography field is empty.</font><br/>";
    }

    if(empty($view)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>View field is empty.</font><br/>";
    }        

    if(empty($forestcover)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>Forest Cover field is empty.</font><br/>";
    }

    if(empty($waterfront)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>Waterfront Access field is empty.</font> 
 <br/>";
    }  

    if(empty($firepit)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>Firepit field is empty.</font><br/>";
    }        

    if(empty($description)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>Description field is empty.</font><br/>";
    }

    if(empty($reslink)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>Reservation Link Access field is empty. 
 </font><br/>";
    }       
} else {    
    //updating the table
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE sites SET 
 sitenumber='$sitenumber',videolink='$videolink',daynight='$daynight',
     maxtents='$maxtents',maxpersons='$maxpersons',geography='$geography', 
     view='$view',forestcover='$forestcover',waterfront='$waterfront', 
     firepit='$firepit',description='$description',reslink='$reslink' WHERE 
 sitenumber=$sitenumber");

    //redirectig to the display page. In our case, it is index.php
    //header("Location: index.php");
}
}
            echo mysqli_error($mysqli);
 ?>
<?php
//getting id from url
$sitenumber = $_GET['site'];

//selecting data associated with this particular id
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM sites WHERE 
sitenumber=$sitenumber");

while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$sitenumber = $res['sitenumber'];
$videolink = $res['videolink'];
$daynight = $res['daynight'];
$maxtents = $res['maxtents'];
$maxpersons = $res['maxpersons'];
$geography = $res['geography'];
$view = $res['view'];
$forestcover = $res['forestcover'];
$waterfront = $res['waterfront'];
$firepit = $res['firepit'];
$description = $res['description'];
$reslink = $res['reslink'];
}
            echo mysqli_error($mysqli);
?>
<html>
<head>    
<title>Edit Data</title>
</head>

<body>
<a href="index.php">Home</a>
<br/><br/>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="edit.php">
    <table border="0">
    <tr> 
            <td>Site Number</td>
            <td><input type="number" name="sitenumber" value="<?php echo 
$sitenumber;?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>YouTube Link</td>
            <td><input type="url" name="videolink" value="<?php echo 
$videolink;?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>Day or Overnight</td>
            <td><select name="daynight" value="<?php echo $daynight;?>">
            <option value="Day">Day</option>
            <option value="Overnight">Overnight</option></td>

        </tr>
                    <tr> 
            <td>Maximum Tents</td>
            <td><input type="number" name="maxtents" value="<?php echo 
$maxtents;?>"></td>
        </tr>
                    <tr> 
            <td>Maximum Persons</td>
            <td><input type="number" name="maxpersons" value="<?php echo 
$maxpersons;?>"></td>
        </tr>
                    <tr> 
            <td>Geography</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="geography" value="<?php echo 
$geography;?>"></td>
        </tr>
                    <tr> 
            <td>View</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="view" value="<?php echo $view;?>"> 
 </td>
        </tr>
                    <tr> 
            <td>Forest Cover</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="forestcover" value="<?php echo 
  $forestcover;?>"></td>
        </tr
                    <tr> 
            <td>Waterfront Access</td>
            <td><select name="waterfront" value="<?php echo $waterfront;?>">
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option></td>
        </tr>
                    <tr> 
            <td>Firepit Availability</td>
            <td><select name="firepit" value="<?php echo $firepit;?>">
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option></td>
        </tr>
                    <tr> 
            <td>Site Description</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="description" value="<?php echo 
$description;?>"></td>
        </tr>
                    <tr> 
            <td>Reservation Link</td>
           <td><input type="url" name="reslink" value="<?php echo $reslink;? 
>"></td>
        </tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="site" value="<?php echo 
$_GET['site'];?>"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry for the long code here, but I felt it was a little necessary to see the full context here.

There is also a break somewhere with the variables.  The sitenumber variable isn't updating, and every variable after that is getting this error...

Notice: Undefined variable: videolink in C:\wamp\www\code\edit.php on line 124

So, this is kind of a two pronged problem.  Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: **Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and will be hacked** even if [you are escaping inputs!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741264/2595450) Use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead. Check: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: In which query you are getting the syntax error??. beacuse I reviewd all your queries but no error.

Comment: It appears to be coming from
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM sites WHERE sitenumber=$sitenumber");

Comment: And I will look into prepared statements.  Like I said, I'm still pretty new to coding.

Comment: @DamienBorden which query you are getting error, update or select??

Comment: It appears to be coming from the SELECT  query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct this :

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM sites WHERE sitenumber='".$sitenumber."' ");
```

And this :

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE sites SET 
sitenumber='$sitenumber',videolink='$videolink',daynight='$daynight',
maxtents='$maxtents',maxpersons='$maxpersons',geography='$geography', 
view='$view',forestcover='$forestcover',waterfront='$waterfront', 
firepit='$firepit',description='$description',reslink='$reslink' WHERE 
sitenumber='$sitenumber'");
```

Comment: This solved my syntax error.  Now I just need to figure out why all my variables are undefined... Thank you.

Comment: You must declare all your variables after 'include_once("config.php"); ' like this : '$sitenumber=""; $videolink=""; '...... until your last variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL query seems good, but the problem can come from the values of your variables.

Since your query is not escaped properly (and [it should be for better security](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)), I would advise you to debug your query before executing.
This way you will be able to understand what is going to be executed in your database.

If you don't use [xdebug](https://xdebug.org), you can just put your query into a variable and then dump it using `var_dump`.

Then, open phpmyadmin (I assume you have an access to it, at least), and paste the value of your variable (which is your query) into the SQL editor. Then execute it and you should have a message explaining where the error is.
It will help you understand why it is important to use prepared statement by seeing which variable has a wrong value (meaning it includes a `'` or a `"`, for instance).

I hope it will help